# Laravel server keep looping on 'Accepted ' , 'Closing'

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-8

My laravel app not working and when i run `php artisan serve`  it terminal looping through Accepted , Closing

```
[Mon Jan 10 12:00:34 2022] PHP 7.4.9 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Mon Jan 10 12:00:37 2022] 127.0.0.1:51825 Accepted
[Mon Jan 10 12:00:37 2022] 127.0.0.1:51826 Accepted
[Mon Jan 10 12:00:37 2022] 127.0.0.1:51826 Closing
[Mon Jan 10 12:00:38 2022] 127.0.0.1:51825 Closing
[Mon Jan 10 12:00:38 2022] 127.0.0.1:51827 Accepted
```

I have tried almost all solution on stack overflow
e.g

- changed port
- Cleared cache
- composer dump-autoload
- Killed cli

This exact code was working fine yesterday.

Comment: I'm using php 7.4

Comment: have you tried running by direct PHP command `php -S localhost:8000` on public folder

Comment: yes i did, didnt work.

Comment: what was the error msg?

Comment: there isn't one in logs but terminal keep printing accepted closing and webpage shows page not working

Comment: @TheDuo Add your solution as an answer to the question and accept it; answers don't go in the question body.

Comment: okay, thanks for suggestion and edit

Comment: if you are stuck with this error, make virtual host with apache or nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same name for two routes (one get and one post). If you get the same error you should check your routes as well.